# Are Adsense link only ads worth a ding dang these days?

Tags: google, google-adsense

About a month ago, and I realize that I tell people to be patient with Google, I placed a block of Adsense link only ads midway down the page of about 700,000 pages. During that tinme, the traffic of my site has been low as expected this time of year, but still I only got 13 impressions verses the over 1000 for all others even on mobile where not all ad blocks are displayed. I expected it to take a while to take off of course, but still in about a month I would have expected more than 13. As far as I know, all I do is cut and paste the code and that is it.

What is the experience with Google Adsense link only ads lately?? Did I miss an important step or something rather obvious??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impressions for link ads are different from regular ad impressions (and lot of people I know get confused because of it).

An impression for a link ad is counted when someone click on a link ad and then is shown plenty of related ads in a separate page. You will make money only if the user click again on any of these ad (may be some without click for CPM ads). However, it works great as chances of second click is very high. That's why very high CTR for link ads (which also confuses people).

In regular ads, when someone browses your page, ads are shown and are counted as impressions.

From your data, 13 impression means that the ads pages (after first click on link unit) are loaded 13 times. Clicks (in case of link ads) refer to second click so you might have got 2-3 of them.

Comment: But how would you say 13 versus 500 or 1000 of the others stack up? I am concerned about an empty ad space and whether I should consider just removing it? I only put it there because G would repeatedly and annoyingly ping me about ad revenue optimization. Yes I would like to make more money, not that I am now, but are these ads worth anything these days??

Comment: 13 vs. 500 - around 2.6% is fine, however, you can improve upon that a little more by experimenting with the position/color etc. They do make money as the CTR for link ad is very high after 1st click. 

I think you can try it for some more time to see results for yourself.

Comment: I did make the ad colors match my theme colors... perhaps I should double-check this and even try the default with a few tweaks. That is a good point! I was just concerned that it was not doing anything at all- let alone whether it made any money. BTW- I do make a coin or two. Before the summer slowdown I really was satisfied except for the traffic. Thanks for your time!!